# How to Retrieve Value by Single Key from StorageDoubleMap in Substrate?

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, storage

I'm developing a `Substrate-based` blockchain and using `StorageDoubleMap` to store label details. The StorageDoubleMap is defined as follows:

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::unbounded]
#[pallet::getter(fn labels)]
pub(super) type Labels<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<
    _,
    Twox64Concat,
    HashId<T>,
    Twox64Concat,
    AccountOf<T>,
    LabelsDetail<T>,
    OptionQuery,
>;
```

I need to retrieve LabelsDetail using just the `label_id (of type HashId<T>)`, without knowing the `AccountOf<T>`.

What are the best practices for this scenario? Is it possible to find the `LabelsDetail` using only `label_id`, or do I need to change my storage structure or use additional indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iter_prefix()` from the StorageDoubleMap to iterate over values that share the first key. You can find one such example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/033d4e86cc7eff0066cd376b9375f815761d653c/frame/nfts/src/features/roles.rs#L133)

Answer (score 1):

Does the on-chain logic really need to find this value itself or is verifying a valid position enough?

The problem is that this could incur an unbound storage iteration and slow down the chain. If this runs on a parachain there would be the chance that it halts when there are lots of entries in the map.
Maybe it is possible to find the entry off-chain and provide the index as *witness* argument to the extrinsic.

If this is not a problem for you, then the `iter_prefix` mentioned above is indeed possible.